# Snackbar not rendering in page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui

I am new to react and am using a snackbar to display the message whether the department was successfully added or failed to the DB. I am using material UI core snackbar for this and using snackbar open and close methods to display and hide the snack bar. However the snackbar is not rendering in the page.

Here is the code:

```
export class AddDepModal extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {sanackbaropen: false, snackbarmsg:''};

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    snackbarClose = (event) =>{
      this.setState({snackbaropen:false});
    };


    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/Department',{
        
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'

        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
          DepartmentID:null,
          DepartmentName: event.target.DepartmentName.value
        })
      })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then((result)=>
        {
          //alert(result);
          this.setState({sanackbaropen:true,snackbarmsg:result})
        },
        (error)=>{
         // alert('Failed')
         this.setState({sanackbaropen:true,snackbarmsg:'failed'})
      
        })

        }
        
    


render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{vertical:"center",horizontal:'center'}}
        open ={this.state.snackbaropen}
        autoHideDuration = {3000}
        onClose={this.snackbarClose}
        message = {<span id= "message-id">{this.state.snackbarmsg}</span>}
        action={[
          <IconButton
          key="close"
          aria-label="Close"
          color="inherit"
          onClick={this.snackbarClose}
          >
            X
          </IconButton>
        ]}    />

       
        <Modal
      {...this.props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Add Department
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        
            <Row>
                <Col sm={6}>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <Form.Group controlId="DepartmentName">
                          <Form.Label>Department Name</Form.Label>
                          <Form.Control
                              type = "text"
                              name="DepartmentName"
                              required
                              placeholder="Department Name"
                              />
                      </Form.Group>
                      <Form.Group>
                          <Button variant="primary" type ="submit">
                              Add Department
                          </Button>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Col>
                </Row>
       
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant= "danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
    </div>
    );
}}

export default AddDepModal;
```

I might be doing something wrong with the open and close statements. Please see.

Comment: You've got some typos: `snackbaropen` and `sanackbaropen` appear to reference the same thing.

Comment: yes just saw that thankyou